# ImageLoader vs Android Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, image-loading

Has anyone had experience with a network image loader library for Android they can recommend?  Specifically I saw these two in my research but am not sure if either is better or more widely used.  Can anyone highlight the differences or pros/cons between the two?

https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader

OR

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: NOSTRA, do you have any thoughts? One question I had was how to just get a bitmap or image data using the universal image loader when I don't have an ImageView.. for instances when I just want to cache an array of images outside of a UI for instance.

Comment: You can use `ImageLoader.loadImage(...)` to get a Bitmap in callback. Try to read Readme.

Comment: I did read the readme and tried using the loadImage method with a callback and I was getting an error.  It was working fine when I did it on an activity but not when I was doing it on the Application class when it didn't have a UI context.   I'll see if I can isolate the error for you.